# How to find the critical points of function $100 + 10 \cos(x) e^{−y^2} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

> The temperature of a square metallic plate, which is defined on the domain $−4 \leq x \leq 4,$ $−4 \leq y \leq 4$, is given by the equation
>   $T(x, y) = 100 + 10\cos (x) e^{−y^2}$.
>
> Compute the positions of all maxima and minima of $T$ on the plate. You may
>   assume that no extrema occur on the edges.

I got $f_x = -10\sin(x)e^{-y^2}$ and $f_y= -20y\cos(x)e^{-y^2}$

Letting $f_x = 0$ you get $\sin(x)=0$ and $x=0, \pi, -\pi, 2\pi, -2\pi,\ \dots$

Letting $f_y=0$ you get $y=0$ and $\cos(x)=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{-3\pi}{2},\ \dots$

So when $y=0$, $x$ should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{-\pi}{2}, \pi, -\pi$ (due to the limits)

But the answers only have $x=\pi$ and $x=-\pi$ and their critical points are $(0,0), (\pi,0)$ and $(-\pi,0)$.

Why do they not include the points $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(0, -\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: Thank you @KoA for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-20y\cos(x)e^{-y^2}$

You wrote $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0\iff (y=0)$ AND $(\cos(x)=0)$ this should be $(y=0)$ OR $(\cos(x)=0)$.

So when $y=0$ you also need also $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ so considering the limits of the plate, $x=0,\pi,-\pi$.

But when $y\neq 0$ we cannot have simultaneously $\cos(x)=\sin(x)=0$ so $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ cannot annulate at the same time.

Comment: Ahh I understand, I think I was just getting confused because there were two variables. Thanks!